# How to get a shade background for R code chunk when writing Rnw file with Knitr in ESS?

Tags: emacs, knitr, ess

Anyone knows how to get a shade background for R code chunk when writing Rnw file with Knitr in ESS? I mean a shade area within ESS window, similar as in R-studio which gives a light grey shade for R code chunk.